# Are there any specific configurations for SSD's on mac?

Tags: ssd

A couple of months ago, I bought an SSD for my MBP. At that time, I remember to have stumbled upon a blog/article suggesting a few options to activate/deactivate.

I cannot find that page again. What are the things to activate/deactivate?

PS : for example, I remember desactivating something about spotlight indexation.

Thanks,

EDIT : (Irrevelant to the question)

A little feedback about the SSD experience. Well I bought my MBP about a year ago. I work in IT sector and create a quite a lot websites. I had the "classic" hdd before it (250go). After a few months, the disk started to make noise. Clicking and ticking. My Mac being absolutely critical, (without it I can't work) I decided to take no risk and to buy an SSD for two reasons :

- First of all, it's shock resistance. I have to move around a lot and my MBP follows me everywhere. And thus is shaken from time to time.
- Secondly beacause of the performance gain.

There are a few other reasons but they were not really decisive in my case.

- Such as noise reduction. Working mostly with a headset noise or not, I won't hear it.
- Battery is supposed to last longer since SSD are less power consuming. In my case, I haven't seen any changes about it. It is not lasting longer or running out of power earlier than before. No changes about that.

Let's say, SSD is a total change. You can buy a new processor three fo four times faster than the one, you had before, double your ram, chagne your motherboard, do whatever yo want. Nothing is going to provide the same performance boost as an SSD.

Even now, nearly 8 months later, performance is still present and not impacted by usage.

Comment: What SSD and any general thoughts after owning it a while? Hardware details on your MBP and drive would be most welcome.

Comment: Edited my question to answer! ;)

Comment: Modern SSDs do not need any special measures to reduce write activity.  They are rated at 100,000 writes per block, and they have wear levelling.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you found this [blog post](http://poller.se/2010/08/optimizing-mac-os-x-for-ssd-drives/). Looks like he changes hibernate to mode 0 (so it doesn't create a sleep image file), mounts the drive in noatime mode. 
A note on TRIM, if you have a sandforce controller in your SSD, like the OWC drives and many (most) of the OCZ drive, it's not recommended to enable TRIM. It can cause instability and these newer controllers are supposed to do  much better cleanup. Intel drives are supposed to benefit quite a bit from TRIM though.

Comment: agree @cftarnas. OWC, OCZ and Intel's latest version SSD are not required you enable TRIM support on Mac OS X. If you do that, however, some weird performance problems will occur.

Comment: Please elaborate on the performance problems - sounds interesting.

Comment: OWC has this [posting](http://blog.macsales.com/11051-to-trim-or-not-to-trim-owc-has-the-answer) that just says it doesn't need it and it can actually hurt reliability and performance. I've seen various postings in other forums by users that have experienced instability with TRIM and sandforce controllers.

Comment: Well, it was not exactly the same blog post but quite close. Thanks for the link. My SSD is a Corsair F80 with a Sandforce controller. I tried TRIM support but performance drastically dropped. Mac OS was totally unusable/laggnig. Everything returned to normal after disabling it again.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you may want to activate manually is [TRIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM_%28SSD_command%29) support. By default, Lion only enables this for the drive models Apple ships themselves. Instructions on how to enable it for any SSD (as long as it does support TRIM) can be found here:

http://www.hardmac.com/news/2011/03/27/the-universal-solution-to-activate-trim

There's no reason to disable Spotlight indexation unless you really don't want to use Spotlight at all, in which case you'll gain a tiny bit of disk space and performance. That's not SSD specific though.

**Update:** Enabling TRIM manually may be counterproductive if your SSD does not correctly implement the command. Check other users experience for your specific SSD model first.

Comment: From what I understood, SSD's are performant enough to enable live search, rather than reading an index created by Spotlight. I will try to look into this. And as said before, TRIM hasn't really helped me... Read mty comment above!

Comment: What do you mean by "live search"? Spotlight will always use an index, as it is impractical to search several hundreds of gigabytes of data for each search request (you'd need a read speed several orders of magnitude faster than an SSD to make this practical). Noted some issues with TRIM command support on certain SSDs/controllers - added a warning to my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Well, by live search I mean a classic full file search. Plus SSD space is generally very limited. Mine is 80 GB for instance. Spotlight nees to update it's index which is (supposed to be) a charge for drives. (A lot of small read/write) which is a prematurely killing SSD. (Which are limited in read/wirte cycles)

Comment: Flash memory is limited in write cycles only (times a block can be erased to be precise), not in read cycles. Thanks to wear leveling, this is not a major concern and does not warrant turning off useful features, unless you actually don't require them. A full file search over 80GB of data is still highly impractical. To get a feeling for this yourself, try `time sudo find -x / -type f -exec grep -il searchterm {} \;` (lists all files in which searchterm occurs on your root volume and measures the time it took - compare this to how long a spotlight search takes).

Comment: I might be wrong, but it thought Spotlight only indexes the file names and not the file contents. If indeed it indexes the content also, that changes alot.

Comment: Spotlight indexes contents too (that's why it has all those importer plugins, like PDF, MS Office and many more). Otherwise `locate(1)` would be sufficient (but even that keeps an index, although only updated once a week).

Comment: @Zenklys let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1121/discussion-between-ingmar-hupp-and-zenklys)